# Need to compare data between two ORACLE tables with different table structure and return the discrepancies

Tags: sql, oracle, compare

I am trying to compare data between two ORACLE tables with different table structure, different column names. I need a ORACLE SQL query that compares the data and returns the unmatched data with their IDs. Both the tables have same ID column which can be used as the comparison link. Could anyone please guide me on this.

Example: TABLE A (ID_A,QTY_A,DATE_A)
Example: TABLE B (ID_B,QTY_B,DATE_B) where ID_A = ID_B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    A.id,
    A.qty_a,
    B.qty_b,
    A.date_a,
    B.date_b
FROM
    Table_A A
FULL OUTER JOIN Table_B B ON B.id = A.id
WHERE
    (
        A.qty_a <> B.qty_b OR
        (A.qty_a IS NULL AND B.qty_b IS NOT NULL) OR
        (A.qty_a IS NOT NULL AND B.qty_b IS NULL)
    ) OR
    (
        A.date_a <> B.date_b
        (A.date_a IS NULL AND B.date_b IS NOT NULL) OR
        (A.date_a IS NOT NULL AND B.date_b IS NULL)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this should suffice:

```
Select  *
From    TableA  A
Join    TableB  B   On  A.Id_A = B.Id_B
Where Not Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    TableB B2
    Where   B2.Id_B = B.Id_B
    And     (A.Qty_A = B.Qty_B Or Coalesce(A.Qty_A, B.Qty_B) Is Null)
    And     (A.Date_A = B.Date_B Or Coalesce(A.Date_A, B.Date_B) Is Null)
)
```

Edit to include `NULL` checking.

Comment: You should probably edit your answer to account for the possibility that the column values might be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(
  (select id_a as id, qty_a as qty, date_a as date from table_a)
   minus
  (select id_b as id, qty_b as qty, date_b as date from table_b)
)
union
(
  (select id_b as id, qty_b as qty, date_b as date from table_b)
   minus
  (select id_a as id, qty_a as qty, date_a as date from table_a)
)
```